# Android Preventing Double Click On A Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, view, spinner, android-spinner

I have an unwanted problem by default in spinner view.

On Android 2.2 when I double click any spinner it opens twice, Upon pressing the back button the 2nd spinner closes but 1st one remains open.

I need a fix for this issue.

I only want the spinner to show once regardless of how many times the user clicks it.

This problem doesn't exist in Android 4.0+.

Is there a way to fix this bug?

Comment: i don't understand why are you double clicking the spinner??

Comment: @MuhammadBabar buddy none wants to double click but sometimes it happens by newby in android or by mistake.

Comment: You don't worry about the things which are the part of framework.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar if somebody needs to fix them... Its a client requirement.

Comment: You can simply set `onClickListener()` on your **Spinner**, in `onClick(View v)` do `mSpinner.setClickable(false)` and in `onItemSelected()` and `onBackPressed()` do `mSpinner.setClickable(true)`

Comment: [see this link to get your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59152242/11383270)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setEnabled(false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) when user click on item first time to prevent further interaction, and make [setEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) when you need.

Comment: Implemented with this but double click is so fast thats why it doesnt work.

Comment: Then the only way you can do this, by setting onTouchListener

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this,

Possibly in your `onClick()`;

```
view.setEnabled(false);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
view.setEnabled(true);
}
}, TIME_IN_MS);
```